# R: How to use named vector to initialize parameter values in mle2

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and need to use it to estimate a MLE. I am using the mle2 function. However since i have many independent variables, I need to pass many parameter values when calling mle2. For example

```
library(bbmle)
x <- mle2(probit, start=list(b0=1,b1=1,b2=1,c0=1,c1=1,d0=1,d1=1),method="BFGS")
```

Instead, I would like to create a vector theta of length 7 and pass that when i call mle2. Something like

```
x <- mle2(probit, start=theta,method="BFGS")
```

Exactly this does not work. Do I need to change how I define the function probit accordingly to use a vector as argument?

I went through the existing threads related to passing vectors as arguments and they suggest using do.call, but can that be used to call mle2? If so, how?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to reduce boilerplate by finding a way to pass a single vector of parameter values. You could achieve this by defining a utility function which converts a single vector of un-named entries into a named list suitable for your model and for `mle2`:

```
## vector of un-named entries
theta <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

## utility function
toList <- function(th) structure(as.list(th), names=c("b0","b1","b2","c0","c1","d0","d1"))
## check
identical(toList(theta), list(b0=1,b1=1,b2=1,c0=1,c1=1,d0=1,d1=1))

## now this should work
x <- mle2(probit, start=toList(theta), method="BFGS")
```